# Issue with Upgrade Laravel 5.3 from 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-upgrade

I am facing issue while upgrading Laravel 5.3 from 5.2.

Following Error occurs

```
 ReflectionException: Class does not exist in /MYPROJECT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:749

[2018-05-08 07:14:18] production.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class  does not exist in /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:749
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749): ReflectionClass->__construct('')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('', Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('', Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('')
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(655): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(629): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(607): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(268): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the upgrade instructions?

Comment: Yes i gone through the upgrade guide...

Comment: Andy, Can you help me out for this issue? I don't know what I have made wrong with this upgrade process.

Comment: Try deleting ./vendor folder and doing `composer update` (if you changed composer.json already reflecting upgrade instructions!) Also try doing `composer dump-autoload -o` -- if that solves your problem you have namespace / autoloading problem.

Comment: Actually my project was in 5.0 version, so i just go through the upgrade process like 5.1, 5.2 and reach to upgrade 5.3. But in 5.3 upgrade process produces above error. Also I am using custom auth controller and composer dump-autoload also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your effort but i have found the issue regarding the given error. It was due to middleware value in RouteSeriveProvider.php file. By mistake I have set its value as blank and it could not find any middleware, so it produces above error.

**app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php** file in **mapWebRoutes** I did set middleware value as blank. If you do not want to provide any middleware then remove the whole middleware line.